# OpenCV / Java works inside the IDE but not from command line (Windows, Netbeans, JavaFX app)

Tags: java, opencv

Please don't mark this as a duplicate. Yes, there are many answers on this and related issues, and I've tried 6 approaches to no avail. Hoping someone can help. The project runs fine from within the Netbeans IDE. Here is what I have tried, followed by the error message ...

1) `F:\Robotics\HeadsUpDisplay>java -jar headsupdisplay.jar`

2) Same error if I use this, with the opencv DLLs and jar file placed in various directories:

```
F:\Robotics\HeadsUpDisplay>java -Djava.library.path="c:\..." -jar headsupdisplay.jar
```

3) It makes no difference if the system PATH points to the same location

4) Same error if I change the java.library.path in the Netbeans project settings

5) It makes no difference if I add the dll library loads separately (here they are all in the root directory of c: as well as the project directory, and the separate dll loads execute without error):

```
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);  
System.load("c:\\opencv_java401.dll");
System.load("c:\\opencv_ffmpeg401_64.dll");
```

6) A LoadLibrary class that someone posted, suitably modified with the current filenames.

The files I am using are:

```
opencv-401.jar
opencv_ffmpeg401_64.dll
opencv_java401.dll
```

Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/opencv/core/Core
        at headsupdisplay.Main.main(Main.java:457)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.opencv.core.Core
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 12 more
Exception running application headsupdisplay.Main
```

Comment: java -cp youlibs.jar;. -Djava.library.path=...

Comment: This is really just a variation on #2, but I did try it. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I just tried porting this application to Eclipse Oxygen using their e(fx) plugin and had no issues. I really like Netbeans better than Eclipse so tried it in Apache Netbeans 9.0 as well. No luck.